# What is the Galois group of the polynomial $f(x)=x^3-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

What is the Galois group of the polynomial $f(x)=x^3-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

$f(x)=0 \ $ gives $x= 3^{1/3},~ \zeta_3 3^{1/3},~ \zeta_3^2 3^{1/3}$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Thus the permutation of these $3$ roots produces the Galois group $S_3$.

Thus the Galois group $G \cong S_3$.

Am I right ?

If I replace the polynomial by $f(x)=x^3-\frac{1}{3}$, then still we get the same Galois group $S_3$.

Am I right ?

Comment: Why do all permutations of the roots correspond to automorphisms? You need to justify that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, if $\sigma$ be an automorphism and $u$ be an root of $f(x)$, then $f(\sigma(u))=\sigma(f(u))=f(u)=0$.Thus $u$ is a root imply $\sigma(u)$ is also a root. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. But that is insufficient to conclude. With $f(x)=x^3-3x+1$ that same argument holds, but the Galois group is cyclic of order three. With $f(x)=x^3-x$ that same argumen holds but the Galois group is trivial.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, We see that the third root of unity $\zeta_3$ and $\zeta_3^2$ do not belong to $\mathbb{Q}$. So an automorphism $\sigma$ don't fix the third root of unity. Hence there are 6 possible maps. Here $\sigma(\zeta_3 3^{1/3})=\sigma(\zeta_3) \sigma(3^{1/3})$ and $\sigma(\zeta_3^2 3^{1/3})=\sigma(\zeta_3^2) \sigma(3^{1/3})$. Can you give the correct explanation please 
?

Comment: Your argument is mostly correct, here the splitting field is $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_3,3^{1/3})$ of degree $6$ over $\Bbb{Q}$, so there are 6 elements in the Galois group and each permutation of the 3 roots is an automorphism. This generalizes to every irreducible cubic with non-square discriminant.

Comment: @reuns, If I take the polynomial $f(x)=x^3+3$ instead of $f(x)=x^3-3$, then the same Galois is obtained. Isn't correct ? Because in that case also the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3, 3^{1/3})$.

Comment: those two polynomials are related by negation, the roots are negated but everything else is the same.

Comment: @rain1,thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Galois group of $x^3-3$ is the group of automorphisms of the splitting field of $x^3-3$ which leave the base field $\mathbb Q$ fixed.

You have found the 3 roots: $\alpha_1 = 3^{1/3}$, $\alpha_2 = \zeta_3 3^{1/3}$, $\alpha_3 = \zeta_3^2 3^{1/3}$. The splitting field of the polynomial is then $\mathbb Q(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$.

An automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$ is an isomorphism from that field to itself and it needs to leave the base field $\mathbb Q$ alone. If $f$ is one of these automorphisms then $\sigma(\alpha_1)$ must be $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ or $\alpha_3$ because $\alpha_1^3-3 = 0$ implies $\sigma(\alpha_1)^3-3 = 0$. So every field automorphisms is a to permutations of the roots.

Notice that $\alpha_3 = \alpha_2^2/\alpha_1$ so $\sigma(\alpha_1)$ and $\sigma(\alpha_2)$ determines $\sigma(\alpha_3)$. This is not a restriction on the permutations we can choose though.

Every (all 6) permutation of the three roots is a field automorphism in this case and that means the Galois group is $S_3$, but this isn't always true.

---

In the example Jyrki Lahtonen mentioned in comments: $x^3 - 3x + 1$ the Galois group is $C_3$. Let the roots of the polynomial be:

- $\beta_1 = $ `-1.8793852415718167681082185546494629399`
- $\beta_2 = $  `1.5320888862379560704047853011108333479`
- $\beta_3 = $  `0.3472963553338606977034332535386295920`

Notice that:

- $1-1/\beta_1 = \beta_2$
- $1-1/\beta_2 = \beta_3$
- $1-1/\beta_3 = \beta_1$

So if $f$ is an automorphism of the field $\mathbb Q(\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3)$ then $f(\beta_1)$ determines $f(\beta_2)$ and $f(\beta_3)$.

This means we can only choose 3 automorphisms and the Galois group is $C_3$.

Comment: So a Galois group of a $3$-degree polynomial is always subset or equal to $S_3$

Comment: Yes the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial of degree n is a transitive group on n points.

Comment: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/T15.html